# Multer not uploading file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload, multer

I am trying to use multer to upload a file from an html form on the client side to the server side, the multer module processes the file on the server side.

The thing here is that everything is ok, because i get the 200 ok response from the server, but the file should be uploaded to my fileSystem and i can't see it.

**This is my html form**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h2>Select a file</h2>
      <input name="curriculum" id="inputVal" type="file">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

**my server side code**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req,file,callback) {
    callback(null, '../files');
  },
  filename: function(req,file,callback) {
    callback(null,Date.now() + file,callback);
  }

})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('curriculum');

router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  upload(req,res, function(err){
    if(err) {
      return res.status(404).send("a error ocurred");
    }
    res.status(200).send("file uploaded");
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my solution based on the npm multer website (server side)

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/upload',upload.single('curriculum') ,function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Ty for the help!

Comment: Do you have the appropriate read/write persmission set to your destination folder where you are trying to upload your files?

Comment: yes i have, i don't get any error, normally i would get a CORS but i allow it in my app file, i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please try adding `/` after files as `callback(null, '../files/');` and see if it is working?

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: before passing req to upload can you try to check if the `req.file.curriculum` contains the file

Comment: inside the /upload route? how can i check outside? i tried the solution in npm multer is simpler it creates the /upload folder but no file inside´

Answer (score 6):

For those having an issue with multer not uploading the file to the destination folder, I found it useful to use the absolute path, rather than a relative path.

Something like this (Absolute path to the node js root directory)
**public/images/pics**

Is better than (Relative path)
**../public/images/pics**

or (Relative path)
**./public/images/pics**

That worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You are not specifying the file you want to upload. Put the name of the `input`.

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('curriculum'), function (req, res, next) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(404).send("a error ocurred");
    }
    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(200).send("file uploaded");
});
```

Also in your file name, make sure your file ends with an extension such as `.png` or `.jpeg` otherwise you will see bunch of bytecodes that do not mean anything.

You can either get the exact file name that your client gives you by using `file.originalname`

```
cb(null, file.originalname)
```

Or you can add it explicitly.

```
callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png')
```

You might want to remove the third parameter of     `callback(null,Date.now() + file,callback)` which is `callback` as it might be bugging the program, and change `+ file` to something like `+ file.originalname` because `file` is an object and the computer might be having problems attending an object to a file name.

**UPDATE**

Main NODEJS

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var app = express()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads')      //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png')
  }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage,
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
      console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){    
    res.render('mult');  //our html document
})

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  console.log(req.file);
  return false;
})
```

HTML FORM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="avatar" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="ssss">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey check my update, these codes work fine for me, you should probably make some changes on your `upload` variable @costacosta